# Solr match all aka *:* does not work

Tags: solr

Don't know what I did wrong. I have two indices with identical documents in it. The local index was replicated from a master which responds correctly, so the same solrconfig.xml and schema.xml file. But if I query the index on my local machine with `*:*` I get 0 docs. (other queries on my local machine are working correct)
I tried jetty and tomcat for the local index. no success.

The `*:*` behaviour is crucial for me, because some test cases are failing now. Do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have [dismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler) set up as the default query handler instead of the [standard one](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler). Check your solrconfig.xml.

Comment: yes, that was the reason, I think + hope. But the strange thing was that it worked on the (master/remote) server ...

Comment: I think I forgot to remove the "default" marker of the 'simple' requestHandler ... so I had 2 default requestHandlers ... stupid me  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `q=*:*` from the query to get all results with dismax

Comment: Actually that only works if you've specified a `q.alt=*:*` parameter in your solrconfiguration.